# Toggle between block 'edit content' and 'select' not properly working in WordPress Admin

Tags: wp-admin, block-editor

I've been struggeling for a while now with toggeling between 'marking / selecting a certain block' and 'editing content' of that block in WordPress' Admin area.

When I click on a specific block in a page's edit screen, it seems to be 'by chance' whether the block will become selected or editable. Mostly, it will be in 'select' mode and I can't change to 'edit content' mode. Whether I use 'Edit / Select' tool from the toolbar of Gutenberg Editor doesn't make any difference.

So, how can I pretictably activate the 'edit block content' mode for any given Gutenberg block? Thanks for any hints.

Wordpress: 5.8.3
Browser: Chromium

Comment: there's no code in your question, are you asking about a specific block or is this a general WP support question for how to use the block editor? This is a programming stack so it's assumed all questions are related to development

Comment: What is the difference? A block will only be selectable, while fields like `RichText` are editable, or not?

Comment: Oh yeah, it's actually not a dev question. Developing my theme and plugin and testing out the website goes all along with each other in my head. When typing in my question I came accross quite a few WP Editor usage question. Hence I assumed it might still be the right place to ask...

Comment: @kero: The difference is, whether you want to, say, move a block to another position or you want to edit content within the block, e.g. write or alter text within a paragraph block.